# Laravel 8 Stripe: PaymentIntent could not be captured because it has a status of requires_action

Tags: stripe-payments, laravel-8, stripe-sca

I am getting the below error. The PaymentIntent could not be captured because it has a status of requires_action. Only a PaymentIntent with one of the following statuses may be captured: requires_capture. This is my code to create a 3d secure payment gateway using stripe.

```
if ($this->paymentMethod == 'pay') {
    $stripe = Stripe::make(env('STRIPE_SK'));

    try {
        $token = $stripe->tokens()->create([
            'card' => [
                'number' => $this->card_no,
                'exp_month' => $this->exp_month,
                'exp_year' => $this->exp_year,
                'cvc' => $this->cvc,
            ]
        ]);

        if (!isset($token['id'])) {
            session()->flash('stripe_error', 'Token not generated');
            $this->order_success = 0;
        }
        $customer = $stripe->customers()->create([
            'name' => $this->fname.' '.$this->lname,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'phone' => $this->contact,
            'address' => [
                'line1' => $this->door_number.' '.$this->road_name,
                'postal_code' => $this->post_code,
                'state' => $this->address,
                'city' => $this->city,
                'country' => $this->country,
            ],
            'shipping' => [
                'name' => $this->fname.' '.$this->lname,
                'phone' => $this->contact,
                'address' => [
                    'line1' => $this->door_number.' '.$this->road_name,
                    'postal_code' => $this->post_code,
                    'state' => $this->address,
                    'city' => $this->city,
                    'country' => $this->country,
                ],
            ],
            'source' => $token['id']
        ]);

        $paymentIntent = $stripe->paymentIntents()->create([
            'customer' => $customer['id'],
            'currency' => 'GBP',
            'amount' => session()->get('checkout')['total'],
            'description' => 'Paid for Order No. '.$order->id,
            'confirm' => true,
            'capture_method' => 'automatic',
            'confirmation_method' => 'automatic',
        ]);
        $charge = $stripe->paymentIntents()->capture($paymentIntent['id']);

        if ($paymentIntent['status'] == 'succeeded') {
            $this->makeTransaction($order->id, 'approved');
            $this->resetCart();
        } else {
            session()->flash('stripe_error', 'Payment not done');
            $this->order_success = 0;
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        # code...
        session()->flash('stripe_error', $e->getMessage());
        $this->order_success = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you create the PaymentIntent and blindly capture it right after. Will your customer be on-session for the flow? If so, it will be easiest if you follow this [guide/flow](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements). You don't handle the case that the payment method will require auth for 3DS.

Comment: I have tried several approaches but no luck m Can you provide assistance in context with the code above, please?